# Create branch to track a given branch in another remote

Tags: git

My branches are tracking the `origin` remote. I am now adding a new remote, let's call it `remote2`:

```
git remote add remote2 https://github.com/blah/blahblah.git
```

and I want to create a new branch in my local clone, let's call it `wip`, to track the `develop` branch of the `remote2` remote. How can I do this? I have tried:

```
git branch -u remote2/develop wip
```

But does not work:

```
fatal: branch 'wip' does not exist
```

Comment: `git branch -u` is for setting the upstream of an *existing* branch. You could create the branch locally first, then use that to set its upstream second. Or you can use axiac's answer to create-with-upstream-set, all in one command; or use other options to `git checkout` to create-with-upstream *and* then check out the branch just created, all three at once. But fundamentally, it really is "create the branch, set its upstream, check it out" and there is nothing wrong with doing that in three commands instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

First, check out the branch you want to track, and then create a new branch from that.

```
git checkout remote2 develop
git checkout -b wip
```

Then you can set it track the right remote branch;

```
git branch -u remote2/develop
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `develop` branch exists only on `remote2` then this command does all the job for you (it also checks the branch out and maybe you don't want it):

```
git checkout --track develop
```

But if the branch `develop` also exists on `remote` then you have to explicitly write the complete [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) command:

```
git branch --track develop remote2/develop
```

`develop` is the name of the new local branch, `remote2/develop` is, of course, the name of the remote branch it tracks.